# how not to show null values in kendo ui mvvm dropdown list

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

Hi I am using kendo ui mvvm and I am trying to populate a dropdown list with a remote data source binding, I can bind the data field to dropdown list but my dropdown list have null values, what i am trying to do is not to show those null values in dropdown list. Here is the problem:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<select style="width:150px;" data-value-field="AttentionTo" data-primitive-value="true" data-bind="source: myds"></select>
  var viewModel = kendo.observable({

        myds: new kendo.data.DataSource({

            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Invoice/GetAllInvoices",
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: 'Data',
                total: 'Total',
                errors: 'Errors',
                model: {
                    id: 'invoiceNumber',
                    fields: {
                        DueDate: {
                            type: "date"
                        },
                        InvoiceDate: {
                            type: "date"
                        },
                        AmountDue: {
                            type: "number"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },


        })

    });

    kendo.bind($("#gridFilters"), viewModel);
```

As you can see, I already tried data-primitive-value="true", but it didn't work,
I am new to kendo mvvm, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to show the "null" values why not exclude these from the dropdown before returning the data back to the UI? eg in your controller code exclude these from the collection.

Comment: Well, I cannot do that, because here I am retrieving a table and using one column for dropdown list and others for other kendo widgets, so I cannot exclude "null" values before i retrieve the dataset, i need to filter null values in dropdown list data source, the answer below is giving the right approach to do that.

Comment: Glad you got the answer you required. I asked the comment purely to try and get an understanding why you had the null values being presented back to the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `data-text-field` attribute on your HTML element.

If you data actually has nulls in it that you want to remove, then you can just [filter your DataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter), like:

```
new kendo.data.DataSource({
    ...
    filter: [
        { field: "AttentionTo", operator: "neq", value: "null" }
    ]
});
```